# When is the last time a trebuchet was used in combat?

Tags: military, warfare, weapons, siege

When was a trebeuchet or any similar weapons (such as an onager, mangonel, catapult) last used in combat?

My guess is that they were replaced by the cannon in the gunpowder age. But I know the cannon was not adopted by everyone at the same time.

So how long exactly was the trebuchet still in use in military warfare?

I'm speaking specifically in terms of military combat, and not its uses in commercial or industrial activities.

Comment: Hi Samid!  Could you share what research you might have done?  I wonder specifically what you found lacking on the wikipedia article on the topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trebuchet#Decline_of_military_use

Comment: Also later in the same page [Uses_in_activism_and_insurgency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trebuchet#Uses_in_activism_and_insurgency) discusses uses in 2013 and 2014.